# Image not getting uploaded on server-PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to use an image as a label for input type=file. I want the upload dialog box to open uplon clicking the image. This seems to work fine. But after submitting the file, the file is not getting through the server, only the file name is getting through. On printing the file size/mime, I get 0/null.
Here's the code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploadimage.php" method="post">
<input style="display:none;" name="image" id="img-input" type='file' onchange="readURL(this);"/>
<label for="img-input">
<img onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='images/nopicture.png';" style="cursor:pointer; border:1px; width:250px;" id="blah" src="#" />
</label>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

EDIT:
here's the javascript:

```
<script>
         function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah')
                    .attr('src', e.target.result)
                    .width(250)
                    .height(200);
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
</script>
```

and here's the file uploadimage.php:

```
<?php
$file=$_FILES['image']['size'];
echo $file."</br>";
$file=$_FILES['image']['name'];
echo $file;
?>
```

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong in the above code, please include javascript and php file that handle the upload task

Comment: @FarzadYZ I just realized it's not the problem with the label. If I try to upload a non-image file (eg, a text file) it's getting uploaded successfully.

Comment: Hello @Harsh , your HTML is working, check this : http://codepen.io/erayalakese/pen/KdqONR . Are you sure your image (nopicture.png is accesible? BTW I don't understand why you are calling your image with onError event instead of `src=` param.

Comment: Also you said you want to use an image as input label, but now you are talking about upload problems :)

Comment: @Eray Hi. Yes I want to use umage as a label for file input field. But after the user clicks on the upload button, the image should also get uploaded on the server.

Comment: You want to upload clicked image to server, right? So please edit your question and title. Meanwhile , i'm working over your problem.

Comment: @Eray, edited the title. :)

Comment: @Eray I guess I found the error. It was probably the max size of image that my server could handle. Uploading a smaller image worked fine. Thanks for the help. :)